# c# Winforms - CLR20r3 Exception

Tags: c#

I am starting run my program in Windows 7 64 bit machine with .Net Framework 4.5 Installed and it's working fine.
Then i try to run in another Windows 7 64 and 32 bit machine with Net Framework 4.5 Installed too, i don't know why the program stopped working.

```
Problem Event Name: CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: ExDraw.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.2.3
  Problem Signature 03: 59be5ce4
  Problem Signature 04: mscorlib
  Problem Signature 05: 4.6.1590.0
  Problem Signature 06: 5787ed44
  Problem Signature 07: f9d
  Problem Signature 08: 96
  Problem Signature 09: System.FormatException
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

And here's my code

```
private void DownloadAddonsListCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = StringHelper.DecryptMyString(e.Result);
        foreach (var line in result.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            var statusAddons = File.Exists("Addons\\" + line.Split('~')[0] + ".addon")
                ? "Installed"
                : "-";

            var localAddonsVersion = "-";
            if (statusAddons != "-")
            {
                localAddonsVersion = File.ReadAllText("Addons\\" + line.Split('~')[0] + ".version");
                if (Convert.ToDouble(localAddonsVersion) < Convert.ToDouble(line.Split('~')[1]))
                    statusAddons = "Outdated";
            }

            var _WebClient = new WebClient();
            var fileName = line.Split('~')[0].Replace(" ", string.Empty) + ".html";
            _WebClient.DownloadFileTaskAsync(line.Split('~')[3],
                RequiredPath.ADDONSDESCRIPTIONPATH + "\\" + fileName).Wait();

            rgvList.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                rgvList.Rows.Add
                (
                    line.Split('~')[0],
                    statusAddons,
                    localAddonsVersion,
                    line.Split('~')[1],
                    line.Split('~')[2],
                    line.Split('~')[3],
                    line.Split('~')[4],
                    RequiredPath.ADDONSDESCRIPTIONPATH + "\\" + fileName
                )));

        }
    }
```

Comment: Since it's a formatException I'd look into the values passed to Convert

Comment: The problem is, it's working fine on my machine. And the value is like 1.0.0.0

Comment: If you can not step into it, use `System.Diagnostics.Trace` to log the data before you convert it. And you can not convert 1.0.0.0 into double, the `FormatException` is to be expected.

Comment: @Luthfi - other machines might not use the dot as their default decimal separator - if you're comparing versions I'd recommend using the built in version class.

Comment: @user6144226  I got it, i'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in

```
if (Convert.ToDouble(localAddonsVersion) < Convert.ToDouble(line.Split('~')[1]))
    statusAddons = "Outdated";
```

You are converting a text into double, but you are doing it in the current culture of the machine. Depending on the culture, the decimal separator can vary; it could be a ".", a "," or even something else. Your problem is most likely related to different cultures an your machines. So when you do these conversions, you should always set a conversion culture.

Your case is a bit different though, since from your comments to the question I get that the data you are trying to compare are version numbers in the format "1.0.0.0". `Double` is a poor choice for a conversion format in this case. The .NET framework comes with the [`System.Version` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.80).aspx) for these kind of comparisons:

```
if (new Version(localAddonsVersion) < new Version(line.Split('~')[1]))
    statusAddons = "Outdated";
```

Comment: The `Version` class is not widely know. Not knowing it doesn't make you stupid.